# what is the meaning of observable definition?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Could you please simply and thoroughly explain below definition?

```
<T, R>(source: Observable<T>) => Observable<R>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a TypeScript function signature. In technical terms, it describes a generic (i.e. parametrically polymorphic) function that accepts two type arguments (T and R), one argument of type Observable (i.e. "observable of type T"), and returns a value of type Observable (i.e. "observable of type R"). If this explanation isn't clear I'd suggest reading about TypeScript generics.

In plainer terms, this describes a function that accepts an observable argument and returns an observable value, though the types of the observables may differ. An simple example of such a function is the "map" function from RxJS.

Answer (score 0):

This is the signature of a pipable operator in RxJS 5.5+

More thorough information can be found here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md